# How to read gulp task names from command params?

Tags: command-line, gulp

I have the following code, which reads what task name I passed to gulp: `release` or `test` and decides what task group to load from the files based on that.

```
var argv = require('yargs').argv;
var group = argv._[0];

var groups = {
    "release": ["tasks/release/*.js", , "tasks/release/deps.json"],
    "test": ["tasks/test/*.js", "tasks/test/deps.json"]
};

require("gulp-task-file-loader").apply(null, groups[group]);
```

Isn't there a better way to get the commanded tasks from gulp itself instead of using `yargs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [great tutorial](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/11/scripting-with-node/) about tools for CLI. According to it I should use [commander](https://github.com/tj/commander.js), so I do so. It is much better than yargs. Another possible solution to use `process.argv[2]` in this case, but it is much better to use a parser in long term.

```
var program = require("commander");
program.parse(process.argv);

var group = program.args[0];

var groups = {
    "release": ["tasks/release/*.js", , "tasks/release/deps.json"],
    "test": ["tasks/test/*.js", "tasks/test/deps.json"]
};

require("gulp-task-file-loader").apply(null, groups[group]);
```